# Keeping Mesh Volume

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, shrinkwrap, retopology

I modelled a figure and already retopologized it. Then I add some subdivision modifiers to increase the details and shrinkwrap to match the volume with the sculpted one. What I want to know is, is there a way to keep the volume of the mesh without applying any modifiers? (this is the shoulder part).

[image: Before]

[image: Subdiv Modifier]

[image: Subdiv + Shrinkwrap]

[image: Modifier]

Comment: you can apply the Shrinkwrap but it won't take the Subdivision Surface into account so it will look slightly different

Comment: yes, but that doesnt keeping the volume like I mention before

Comment: no you can't keep the volume, you'll need to correct afterwards